# What means a NTH search?

Tags: java

maybe this is a basic question... but I really don't know what means or what this refer to.

I searched into this and I find the nth largest and Smallest but still this topics doesn't explain what nth means.

If some one knows, it would be a big help.

Comment: `n`th means `n`th element in the list from where you're searching. You should probably google these stuff before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*n*-th generally denotes some member of a series or list. You can treat it sort of like a variable. For example, "do something to the nth item on the nth iteration through a list" would mean that you do something to the first item on the first iteration, second item on the second iteration, and so on and so forth.